# Rails app not working, development mode, apache, viewing externally

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, centos

I have rails on a CENTOS 6.x VirtualBox guest with a Win7 host. I made a demo app and I can see the Welcome "You’re riding Ruby on Rails!" default page from the host browser. However, when I do

```
demo> rails generate controller Say hello goodbye
```

I get "something went wrong" when I navigate to .../Say/hello

I also notice that I get a "something went wrong" message inside the element of the "About your application's environment" page linked off the Welcome index.

I have:

- turned off selinux
- edited the text of the welcome screen and viewed the difference (from host browser) to verify I'm working in the right place
- come here to look for help

Comment: That message is given in production mode, in development you should see the actual error and backtrace. Have you set `RailsEnv 'development'` in your Apache config?

Comment: No, I'll try that. Would that explain the error on the /Say/hello page too, or would that just give me more detail?

Comment: @Thilo - you rock. That showed me the mysql2 error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)"

Comment: Cool, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message "something went wrong" is given in production mode, in development you should see the actual error and backtrace. Make sure to specify the environment in your Apache config with

```
RailsEnv 'development'
```